# How to add the data in the same row index but in different cells in each colomn

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I got a dictionary list:

```
data_list = [
{"ID":id},
{"HomeOwnersDwellingCoverageALimitof":HomeOwnersDwellingCoverageALimitof},
{"HomeOwnersPersonalPropetyReplacemntCostOpt":HomeOwnersPersonalPropetyReplacemntCostOpt},
{"HomeOwnersLossOfUserCoverageDeduc":HomeOwnersLossOfUserCoverageDeduc},
{"HomeOwnersOtherStructuresCoverageBLimit":HomeOwnersOtherStructuresCoverageBLimit},
{"HomeOwnersPersonalpropety":HomeOwnersPersonalpropety},
{"HomeOwnersLossOfUserCoverageD":HomeOwnersLossOfUserCoverageD},
{"HomeOwnersPersonalLiabilityCovarageE":HomeOwnersPersonalLiabilityCovarageE},
{"HomeOwnersMedicalPayments":HomeOwnersMedicalPayments},
{"HomeOwnersOtherStructuresCoverageBLimitDeduc":HomeOwnersOtherStructuresCoverageBLimitDeduc},
{"HomeOwnersPersonalpropetyDeduc":HomeOwnersPersonalpropetyDeduc},
{"HomeOwnersPersonalLiabilityCovarageEDeduc":HomeOwnersPersonalLiabilityCovarageEDeduc},
{"HomeOwnersMedicalPaymentsDeduc":HomeOwnersMedicalPaymentsDeduc},
{"HomeOwnersFullValueReplacementCostOpt":HomeOwnersFullValueReplacementCostOpt},
{"HomeOwnersInflationGuardOpt":HomeOwnersInflationGuardOpt},
{"HomeOwnersLossAssessmentOpt":HomeOwnersLossAssessmentOpt},
{"HomeOwnersUnscheduledJewerlyOpt":HomeOwnersUnscheduledJewerlyOpt},
{"HomeOwnersServiceLineOpt":HomeOwnersServiceLineOpt},
{"HomeOwnersIdentityFreaudExpenseOpt":HomeOwnersIdentityFreaudExpenseOpt},
{"HomeOwnersMechanicalBreakdownOpt":HomeOwnersMechanicalBreakdownOpt},
{"HomeOwnersBuildingOrdinanceOpt":HomeOwnersBuildingOrdinanceOpt},
{"HomeOwnersFullValueReplacementCostLimit":HomeOwnersFullValueReplacementCostLimit},
{"HomeOwnersPersonalPropetyReplacemntCostLimit":HomeOwnersPersonalPropetyReplacemntCostLimit},
{"HomeOwnersInflationGuardLimit":HomeOwnersInflationGuardLimit},
{"HomeOwnersLossAssessmentLimit":HomeOwnersLossAssessmentLimit},
{"HomeOwnersUnscheduledJewerlyLimit":HomeOwnersUnscheduledJewerlyLimit},
{"HomeOwnersServiceLineLimit":HomeOwnersServiceLineLimit},
{"HomeOwnersIdentityFreaudExpenseLimit":HomeOwnersIdentityFreaudExpenseLimit},
{"HomeOwnersMechanicalBreakdownLimit":HomeOwnersMechanicalBreakdownLimit},
{"HomeOwnersBuildingOrdinanceLimit":HomeOwnersBuildingOrdinanceLimit},
{"HomeOwnersFullValueReplacementCostDeduc": HomeOwnersFullValueReplacementCostDeduc},
{"HomeOwnersPersonalPropetyReplacemntCostDeduc": HomeOwnersPersonalPropetyReplacemntCostDeduc},
{"HomeOwnersInflationGuardDeduc": HomeOwnersInflationGuardDeduc},]
```

I added this to an Excel file, the problem is the data is not below each column, is added with one row down I will share an image with the Excel:

[image: Actual result - Excel file]

For this method, I use this line of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
name_exel = 'HomeOwners_results.xlsx'

df.to_excel(name_exel,index=False, header=True,startrow=0,startcol=0)
```

I tried other solutions like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column'])


for item in data_list:
    for key, value in item.items():
        df = df.append({'Column': value}, ignore_index=True)

name_excel = 'HomeOwners_results.xlsx'
df.to_excel(name_excel, index=False, header=False)

print(df)
```

but now the date is added in column A and in the rows for 1 to 10 or to how much data I got in the list.

And I am out of ideas on how to that to get the data like:
[image: Expected result]

Comment: Answer create one row DataFrame, no 2 columns DataFrame, so reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested dictionary comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{k: v for d in data_list for k, v in d.items()}])
```

Or [`ChainMap`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

df = pd.DataFrame([ChainMap(*data_list)])
```

---

```
df.to_excel(name_exel,index=False, header=True,startrow=0,startcol=0)
```

Comment: But if I got a dictionary with the key that got the value a list it returns me an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'